# ERROR: path[1]="": No such file or directory when publishing rCharts Highcharts with shinyapps

Tags: r, rstudio, rcharts, shiny

I am trying to publish a webapp using rCharts Highcharts to shinyapps and I get the following error

```
ERROR: path[1]="": No such file or directory
```

But strangely enough the webapp works flowlessly on my laptop while testing.

I looked around, and I seem the only one that has the problem.  I could not find any reference to that.

I tried to reconstruct the error with a test app.  The simpler example I could make is below.

Ui.R is the following

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Subset mtcars data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("features",
                         label = h3("Features to display"),
                         choices = list("disp" = 1, "hp" = 2),
                         selected = c(1,2) ),
      checkboxGroupInput("cars",
                         label = h3("Cars to display"),
                         choices = list("Mazda RX4" = "Mazda RX4",
                                        "Mazda RX4 Wag" = "Mazda RX4 Wag",
                                        "Datsun 710" = "Datsun 710",
                                        "Hornet 4 Drive" = "Hornet 4 Drive",
                                        "Hornet Sportabout" =  "Hornet Sportabout",
                                        "Valiant" = "Valiant"),
                         selected = c("Mazda RX4","Mazda RX4 Wag","Datsun 710",
                                      "Hornet 4 Drive","Hornet Sportabout","Valiant") ) ),
    mainPanel(
      showOutput("barChart", "Highcharts")
    ) ) ) )
```

server.R is

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
data= head(mtcars)[,c("disp", "hp")]
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$barChart <- renderChart2( { 
    # column selection
    if (!(1 %in% input$features)) { data$disp=NULL }
    if (!(2 %in% input$features)) { data$hp=NULL }
    # rows selection
    data= data[input$cars,]
    # chart
    barChart.chart <- Highcharts$new()
    barChart.chart$chart(type = "column")
    barChart.chart$title(text = "Subset mtcars data")
    barChart.chart$xAxis(categories = rownames(data))
    barChart.chart$yAxis(title = list(text = "Number of Refugees"))
    barChart.chart$data(data)
    barChart.chart$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
    return(barChart.chart) } ) } )
```

The app works fine in the local environnment, but it fails when pushed to shinyApps.io.  Here is my procedure and the messages I get:

```
> deployApp(appName = "PathFault",lint = TRUE) # Lint should be TRUE by default but I force it anyway
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 75795...
Detecting system locale ... de_DE
DONE
Deploying bundle: 340000 for application: 75795 ...
Waiting for task: 121937348
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 334046
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  unstaging: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://legru.shinyapps.io/PathFault
>
```

but opening https://legru.shinyapps.io/PathFault reveals the error.

The log reveals the following:

```
> showLogs(appName = "PathFault")
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597553+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: R version: 3.2.3
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597645+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: shiny version: 0.12.2
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597646+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: rmarkdown version: NA
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597647+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: knitr version: NA
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597648+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: jsonlite version: 0.9.19
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597661+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0
2015-12-28T07:05:54.597662+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-12-28T07:05:54.808343+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Using jsonlite for JSON                         processing
2015-12-28T07:05:54.811938+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: 
2015-12-28T07:05:54.811940+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Starting R with process     ID: '11'
2015-12-28T07:05:54.816505+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: 
2015-12-28T07:05:54.816508+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Listening on     http://0.0.0.0:57737
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971541+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: R version: 3.2.3
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971671+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: shiny version: 0.12.2
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971673+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: rmarkdown version: NA
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971675+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: knitr version: NA
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971701+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: jsonlite version: 0.9.19
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971703+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: RJSONIO version: 1.3.0    
2015-12-28T07:06:00.971718+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: htmltools version: 0.2.6
2015-12-28T07:06:01.172811+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Using jsonlite for JSON     processing
2015-12-28T07:06:01.176769+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: 
2015-12-28T07:06:01.176771+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Starting R with process     ID: '26'
2015-12-28T07:06:01.181306+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Listening on     http://0.0.0.0:54220
2015-12-28T07:06:01.181304+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: 
2015-12-28T07:06:01.342999+00:00 shinyapps[75795]: Error in     normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
2015-12-28T07:06:01.343004+00:00 shinyapps[75795]:   path[1]="": No such     file or directory
```

In my test I verified that if I comment out "showOutput("barChart", "Highcharts")" in ui.R there is no error (but no chart ;-( ).  It seems to be a problem with Highcharts and shinyapps.

My environment:

I am working on Windows 10

> R.version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          2.3
>   year           2015
>   month          12
>   day            10
>   svn rev        69752
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
>   nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree

shiny version: 0.12.2
rCharts version: 0.45

I pubhish the app using RStudio Version 0.99.489

I hope that somebody can help

Comment: I am not sure what it's your problem but the your app is working for me and I don't have en error message as you described.

Comment: The app works fine in the local environment,  but when I publish it on shinyapps I get the error.  Something breaks when I transfer to the shinyapps server.

Comment: Thanks MLavoie I edited the question adding the deployment procedure and the logs I got from the server.  I hope that now the question is somewhat clearer.

Comment: Did you get it resolved?

Comment: Hi Tim,  I did find a work around using ggplot,  but I was not so happy with it.  No I did not resolve the problem and since there was no answer for a while I moved on to do other pressing things.  I want to go back to that project but it will not be before May.

Comment: I'd love to have a solution to this, if you find it please post. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The "h" in "Highcharts" needs to be lowercase:

```
showOutput("barChart", "highcharts")
```

If that doesn't work: For the deployment, showOutput needs you  to detail the path to your highcharts-lilbrary (at least in my case, for whatever reason ^^).

I had a problem which was very similar to yours. Here's my solution:
["ERROR: path[1]="": No such file or directory" when publishing Parallel Coordinates Chart with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691327/error-path1-no-such-file-or-directory-when-publishing-parallel-coordina/36768206#36768206)